# highlight specific text in TextArea

Tags: javascript, html

I need to simulate a find and replace function in my webpage using javascript, no matter with find and replace, but the problem is how to highlight the matched search results inside the textArea before replacing them.
I tried to replace matched results with with Bold Tag but it doesn't work because the textArea don't understand HTML tags.

I have used the following code:

```
function findMyText(searchTxt) {

 var textAreaTxt = "";

 textAreaTxt = document.getElementById("myTxtAreaID").value;
 var match = new RegExp(searchTxt, "ig");     
 var boldText = '<B>' + searchTxt+ '<\/B>';
 var replaced = textAreaTxt .replace(match, boldText);

 document.getElementById("myTxtAreaID").value= replaced;
}
```

is there any other way to highlight search results in textArea , or how to make textArea understand HTML Tags

Thanks in advance

Comment: When asking about HTML DOM / JS problems in a JSF page, you should rightclick page in webbrowser and do *View Source* to see the generated HTML source code and base your question on that.

Comment: My question is pure javascript , it is just inside a jsf page

Comment: JavaScript do not know anything about JSF components. JSF runs in webserver and produces HTML. JavaScript runs in webbrowser and works with the generated HTML output of JSF. Once again, rightclick page in browser and do *View Source* to see the generated HTML output and base your JavaScript code and your question on exactly that.

Comment: Thanks for your Consideration , but I think you didn't understand me , I know that jsf elements should have full ID in javascript code , the attached code is a simple one.

Comment: @BalusC, egy is right, that's the JS code contained in the html page and the one that does the replacement.. the rest of the html page is not relevant

Comment: @red: I was just referring to unnecessary `[jsf]` tag in initial question which I removed. See edit history.

Comment: be sure to see the regexp with a "g" flag that mean that the op want to make multiple highlight at the same time not a single occurence so selecting the text is not a good substitute

Answer (score 11):

```
t = document.getElementById("myTxtAreaID");
l = t.value.indexOf(searchText);
if(l!=-1){
t.selectionStart = l;
t.selectionEnd = l+searchText.length
}
```

What that code does is find the beginning of the found text and set the selectionStart and selectionEnd values for the textarea. That simply selects the text as if the user had selected the text himself. Working [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhjZH/1/)

Comment: this may select the text, but is not really like a highlight at all. if the user select another part of the text the highlight is gone elsewhere not what the author seems to want

Comment: Agreed, but aren't down votes for specifically harmful answers? I see that this isn't EXACTLY what the OP wanted, but it's a good enough substitute.

Comment: Helped me with a related problem, so +1.

Comment: Simples e eficiente, tudo que precisava. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think the only possible ways to do that are:

- use javascript canvas drawing to highlight text inside the textarea (?? quite complex i think)
- use a "fake" textarea, built using an iframe, like what wysiwyg editors (ckeditor, tinymce, ..) do

Comment: not sure about the canvas way but the other is the only solution i can see

Answer (score 2):

A textarea can't render htmltags you have to hide your textarea and render the content in a div or an iframe. It's the techniques used by many wysiwyg editors.
Another way can be to use a contentEditable div

Comment: I didn't know about contentEditable divs, I just googled and tried some examples, but it seems they don't work in the same way on all browsers.. (they have different problems on firefox 3.6 and 6.0; works nicely on chrome, ..)

Comment: yes they don't behave the same in different browsers it's really hard to make stuff with that. The most simple in your case is to just render the content of the textarea in a separate div, when changing the textarea then update the content of the div